# Get value from array and put it in text label

Tags: iphone, ios, button, nsarray, uilabel

I have a `application` where you press a `button` and when you pressed the button the label changes in a random word. But when i press the button my `label` disappear.

What should i do?

This is the code:

```
 if (sender == self.button) {

        NSString*path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"wordss" ofType:@"plist"];
        words = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [self.randomLabel setText:[self.words objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([self.words count])]];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Label is not disappearing the problem is you are setting empty string as the selected random value is returning null value.

```
NSString*path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"wordss" ofType:@"plist"];
words = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog("%@",words);
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:[self.words objectAtIndex:((arc4random() % [self.words count]) + 0)]]
NSLog("%@",string);
[self.randomLabel setText:string];
```

check that nslog statement's are not null

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the output of:

arc4random_uniform([self.words count])

And, also since label can take NSString, so you need to cast int back to NSString. So, do like that:

```
NSString *myGeneratedRandNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random_uniform([self.words count])];
```

Then, set this string to your label, like that:

```
[myLabel setText:myGeneratedRandNumber];
```

Also note, working of this function:

The following will generate a number between 0 and 73 inclusive.

```
arc4random_uniform(74);
```

Comment: Tnx it worked almost only the label shows the number instead of the string. how is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you. Please clarify what do you want to know? Please let me know. :)

Comment: in the words.plist every sting has a key like item o, item 1 etc. When i press the button the label shows the key instead of of the value of the key

Comment: So, you need to get the value correspond to that key. I think, it's little bit easy.:)